# Deploying a dacpac with references to other dacpacs

Tags: sql, database, deployment, sql-server-data-tools

I need to deploy a dacpac to a database, however the dacpac references other dacpacs, in the same database project, that touch other databases. I need to keep the structure as it is, since I'm working on legacy code. How do I deploy my dacpac without using those other dacpacs?

I'm getting an error similar to: [MSDeploy/WebDeploy - Deploy Composite Database Project via DacPac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27365631/msdeploy-webdeploy-deploy-composite-database-project-via-dacpac)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I haven't had any problems doing a build/publish. The build copies all referenced dacpacs into the same folder as everything else built. The publish pushes the changes for the current DB only to the system. We use msbuild.exe for the build and sqlpackage.exe to publish.

Comment: @PeterSchott Thanks for the help, I couldn't find any clear documentation on whether or not it changed the other databases.

Comment: When you deploy you specify one target database, it won't deploy to multiple databases so you should be fine.

Comment: And you can always choose the option to just generate a script to see what will be changed. (and/or an XML change report - I find those useful for a big picture overview, even though it doesn't show pre/post deploy script changes)